# React Leaflet: Map Resizing onClick/Dynamic Button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-leaflet

```
let style;
if(this.state.getMoreInfo){
  style = {
    height: "78vh",
    width: "75%",
  };
} else {
  style = {
    height: "78vh",
    width: "100%",
  };
}


<div className="mapContent">
  <Map 
    className="Map" 
    style={style} 
    center={{ lat: 40.7 , lng: -74 }} 
    zoom={15} 
    onClick={this.addMarker}>
    <TileLayer
      attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
    />
    {this.state.data.map((house, idx) => 
      <Marker 
        key={`marker-${idx}`} 
        position={{ lat: house.latitude, lng: house.longitude }} 
        icon={ Icon } >
        <Popup>
          <Card className="housePopup">
            <CardHeader tag="h5">{house.address}</CardHeader>
            <CardBody className="houseDescription">
              <CardText>{house.description}</CardText>
            </CardBody>
            <Button 
              value={house} 
              onClick={() => this.setState({
                getMoreInfo: true, 
                currHouse: house 
              })}>
              Get More Info
            </Button>
          </Card>
        </Popup>
      </Marker>
    )}
  </Map>                
  { this.state.getMoreInfo 
    ? (<HouseInfo house={this.state.currHouse}/>) 
    : (<div></div>)}
</div>
```

The above is the snippets of my react class component.  I am currently using the React Leaflet library to generate a map for my project.  My goal is to generate a specific sidebar upon clicking the more info button.  Essentially, I want to make a dynamic button that is specific to the element in the array. However, every time I click on the button, the page goes blank.  I tried testing to set the map at a smaller width without the additional information, and it worked.  I am guessing it might be a problem with my logic on how I created the button.  Any thoughts?

Comment: The page goes blank, like the sidebar is present but the map disappears? Or the whole page crashes? Do you get any errors in your console?

Comment: @SethLutske I have a Navbar and footer that remain, but the part of the page where the map should be becomes blank.  The page itself becomes super long.  I have to scroll all the way to the bottom to see the footer.  The sidebar is nonexistent.

Comment: Something is clearly going sideways with your css.  But the code you've posted is not enough to figure it out. See if you can give us a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can help debug.  If you create a functioning codesandbox that reproduces the problem, even better

Comment: @SethLutske You were right. I checked my css.  Minor, but fatal mistake.  I'll be sure to add more info to my posts last time.